# Is more efficient GROUP BY or JOIN?

Tags: sql, pyspark

Hi i have this table and i want to know what query is mor efficient:

```
   [ID_SOGGETTO]
  ,[COGNOME]
  ,[NOME]
  ,[DENOMINAZIONE]
  ,[FISICA_GIURID]
  ,[CODICEFISCALE]
  ,[PARTITAIVA]
  ,[ID_COMUNE]
  ,[DATA_NASCITA]
  ,[RAE]
  ,[SAE]
  ,[TIPO_SOCIETA]
  ,[NDG]
  ,[CODICECCIAA]
  ,[CODICECR]
  ,[ATTIVITALAVORATIVA]
  ,[PROFESSIONISTA]
  ,[CODICEFORNITORESAP]
  ,[TRASFERITOSAP]
  ,[ALBOPRECS]
  ,[ID_USER]
  ,[ID_USERINC]
  ,[ID_VERSIONE]
  ,[DATA_AGGIORNAMENTO]
  ,[DATA_STORICIZZAZIONE]
```

And i tried this query to select all rows where that have same "Partita iva" and different "ID_SOGGETTO":

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE PARTITAIVA IN ( SELECT PARTITAIVA FROM table GROUP BY PARTITAIVA HAVING COUNT(distinct ID_SOGGETTO) > 1)
```

It's more efficient with a JOIN?

Comment: Do you have a primary key in the table?

Comment: Group by is for aggregation on data   ... JOIN if for relatione between tables  ..  you question is not clear ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the most efficient way to do what you want uses window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (DENSE_RANK()OVER (PARTITION BY PARTITAIVA ORDER BY ID_SOGGETTO ASC) +
              DENSE_RANK()OVER (PARTITION BY PARTITAIVA ORDER BY ID_SOGGETTO DESC)
             ) as cnt
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

The sum of `DENSE_RANK()` is simply a way to calculate the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

In other databases, `EXISTS` would be recommended:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.partitaiva = t.partitaiva and
                    t2.id_soggetto <> t.id_soggetto
             );
```

However, I am not sure if this would be faster in SparkSQL.

Comment: Typically `spark.sql()` is going to be faster to use. Building a temp table and using `spark.sql()` will typically be much faster for processing and performance, especially if you are dealing with big data.